# Android TextUtils isEmpty vs String.isEmpty

Tags: java, android

What is difference between `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` and `string.isEmpty`?

Both do the same operation.

Is it advantageous to use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`?

Comment: You know you can always just look at the implementation of both methods to figure out the difference yourself in just a few seconds...

Comment: TextUtils Source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/TextUtils.java#TextUtils.isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 82):

Yes, `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` is preferred.

---

For `string.isEmpty()`, a null string value will throw a `NullPointerException`

`TextUtils` will always return a boolean value.

In code, the former simply [calls the equivalent of the other](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/TextUtils.java#TextUtils.isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), plus a null check.

```
return string == null || string.length() == 0;
```

Comment: @RuchirBaronia that means `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` check also if the `String` object is `null` or not so if you try to use that `String` you didn't get `NullPointerException`

Comment: @ahmedghanayem No, I was asking why cricket wrote String#isEmpty instead of String.isEmpty, but that link cleared that up for me.

Comment: I realized I could simply use the variable instead of the class to avoid further confusion

Comment: “always preferred” is a strong phrase. For references which should not be `null`, it’s actually preferred to use a method that will fail immediately, if the application is in an inconsistent state, rather than continuing with an assumption like “`null` is equivalent to an empty string” and fail at some unspecific later point.

Comment: I don't think I've ever had an occurrence where I wanted a null string.

Comment: @cricket_007 Precisely, so if you _did_ get a null string it's better to know about it immediately instead of masking the problem with `TextUtils.isEmpty`. You want `TextUtils` when working with strings which you do expect can be `null` e.g. because they are returned from some `null`-using API.

Comment: latter*(later)  
former*(first)

Answer (score 11):

In class `TextUtils`

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

checks if string length is zero and if string is null to avoid throwing `NullPointerException`

in class `String`

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return count == 0;
}
```

checks if string length is zero only, this may result in `NullPointerException` if you try to use that string and it is null.

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but why are they not just doing: return if {str == null || str.length() == 0;}

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the doc

for the [String#isEmpty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) they specify:

> boolean
>   isEmpty() 
>             Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

and for the [TextUtils.isEmpty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))   the documentation explains:

> public static boolean isEmpty (CharSequence str)
>
> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

so the main difference is that using the TextUtils.isEmpty, you dont care or dont need to check if the string is null referenced or not,

in the other case yes.

Answer (score 5):

`TextUtils.isEmpty()` is better in Android SDK because of inner null check, so you don't need to check string for null before checking its emptiness yourself.

But with Kotlin, you can use `String?.isEmpty()` and `String?.isNotEmpty()` instead of `TextUtils.isEmpty()` and `!TextUtils.isEmpty()`, it will be more reader friendly

So I think it is preferred to use `String?.isEmpty()` in Kotlin and `TextUtils.isEmpty()` in Android Java SDK

Comment: Using TextUtils.isEmpty() return false even if it is empty while running tests. It needs static mocking. If you are using Kotlin use isNullOrBlank() or isNullOrEmpty() methods instead. You don't need any mocking for tests.

Answer (score -2):

```
String?.isNullOrEmpty
```

might be what you are looking for

Comment: This is a java question.