# Error while trying to sign up using email and password using firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase

I am having this error while trying to run this code in android studio:

Error:

```
2019-02-07 20:16:50.708 30406-30406/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-07 20:16:50.708 30406-30406/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-02-07 20:16:50.709 30406-30406/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2019-02-07 20:17:05.426 30406-30406/com.example.servicees E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2019-02-07 20:17:25.789 30406-30406/com.example.servicees E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.servicees, PID: 30406
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source:232)
        at com.example.servicees.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6909)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Code:

```
package com.example.servicees;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText etName, etService, etDes, etCost, etContact, etPass, etEmail;
    Button offer;
    CountryCodePicker ccp;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etName = findViewById(R.id.enterName);
        etService = findViewById(R.id.enterService);
        etDes = findViewById(R.id.enterDescription);
        etCost = findViewById(R.id.enterCost);
        etContact = findViewById(R.id.enterContact);
        etPass = findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
        ccp = findViewById(R.id.ccpLogin);

        /*final String putName=etName.getText().toString();
        final String putService=etService.getText().toString();
        final String putDes=etDes.getText().toString();
        final String putCost=etCost.getText().toString();
        //final String putPass=etPass.getText().toString();
        final String putEmail=etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String putPass=etPass.getText().toString();*/


        ccp.registerCarrierNumberEditText(etContact);

        //final String fullNumber = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();

        offer = findViewById(R.id.offerBtn);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        offer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             String putName=etName.getText().toString().trim();
             String putService=etService.getText().toString().trim();
             String putDes=etDes.getText().toString().trim();
             String putCost=etCost.getText().toString().trim();
             String putEmail=etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
             String putPass=etPass.getText().toString().trim();
             //ccp.registerCarrierNumberEditText(etContact);

             String fullNumber = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(notEmpty()){
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(putEmail, putPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            User user = new User(putName, putService, putDes, putCost, fullNumber, putPass, putEmail);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(putEmail).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Fields Are Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public boolean notEmpty() {
        Boolean checker;
        String checkEmName = etName.getText().toString();
        String checkEmService = etService.getText().toString();
        String checkEmDes = etDes.getText().toString();
        String checkEmCost = etCost.getText().toString();
        String fullNumberCh = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();
        String checkEmEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String checkEmPass = etPass.getText().toString();
        if (checkEmName.isEmpty() || checkEmService.isEmpty() || checkEmDes.isEmpty() || checkEmCost.isEmpty() || fullNumberCh.isEmpty() || checkEmEmail.isEmpty() || checkEmPass.isEmpty())
            checker = false;
        else
            checker = true;
        return checker;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Given String is empty or null` ... Well, did you put text in the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move each of those `getText().toString()` into the `onClick`.

Otherwise, you are getting empty strings upon attaching the click listener to the button (i.e. before you type any text)

Also, you might want to see [Android TextUtils isEmpty vs String.isEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388581/android-textutils-isempty-vs-string-isempty)

Comment: Now I am having this error : 2019-02-08 13:56:40.869 13334-13334/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-08 13:56:40.870 13334-13334/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-02-08 13:56:40.870 13334-13334/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2019-02-08 13:56:58.845 13334-13334/com.example.servicees E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
I moved the getText().toString() into the onClick.

Comment: I am trying to launch my app on Samsung Galaxy J6.

Comment: Those errors aren't causing your app to crash. Look at lines that include "Caused by" or "Fatal exception". And my answer should fix the issue mentioned in the question, it's not designed to fix future problems

Comment: I now fixed this issue as well. Actually I was using the already registered email ids by mistake. But anyways thanks for your help it proved valuable. :)